# Menu is made from Controller, how can I change a particular menu item with <span>

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu made from

```
'profile' => ['heading' => 'Update your bio, cover and avatar', 'icon' => 'person', 'test' =>'test2'],
        'account' => ['heading' => 'Manage your account settings', 'icon' => 'settings'],
        'wallet' => ['heading' => 'Your payments & wallet', 'icon' => 'wallet'],
        'payments' => ['heading' => 'Your payments & wallet', 'icon' => 'card'],
        'rates' => ['heading' => 'Prices & Bundles', 'icon' => 'layers'],
```

Then, in blade:

```
 <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        @include('elements.icon',['icon'=>$setting['icon'].'-outline','centered'=>'false','classes'=>'mr-3','variant'=>'medium'])
                        <span>{{ucfirst(__($route))}}</span>
                    </div>
```

So, how, can I , on blade, add a test to menu with name "Wallet"

I tried make some @IF but doesn't work

Comment: what is `$route`?

Comment: It looks like your blade is missing a `for` loop. It might be easier to help you if you added that.  Also, your top PHP looks like it's not a complete line of code.  And it would be easier to read if it was indented better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define the 'test' for 'wallet' in the menu array:

> ```
> $menu = [
>     'profile' => ['heading' => 'Update your bio, cover and avatar', 'icon' => 'person', 'test' =>'test2'],
>     'account' => ['heading' => 'Manage your account settings', 'icon' => 'settings'],
>     'wallet' => ['heading' => 'Your payments & wallet', 'icon' => 'wallet', 'test' => 'testValue'],
>     'payments' => ['heading' => 'Your payments & wallet', 'icon' => 'card'],
>     'rates' => ['heading' => 'Prices & Bundles', 'icon' => 'layers'],
> ];
> ```

In this example, I added a 'test' key to the 'wallet' array with a value of 'testValue'.

Then, in your Blade template, you can access this value like this:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    @include('elements.icon',['icon'=>$setting['icon'].'-outline','centered'=>'false','classes'=>'mr-3','variant'=>'medium'])
    <span>{{ucfirst(__($route))}}</span>
    @if (isset($setting['test']))
        <span>{{$setting['test']}}</span>
    @endif </div>
```

Here, I've used an @if directive to check if the 'test' key is set for the current menu item ($setting). If it is, then the value of 'test' is displayed. If it's not, nothing is displayed.

Comment: I m not developer, but, I was trying in the same way, just haven't finished it. BIG THANKS FOR U!

Answer (score 0):

In your blade, when you loop through your menu items, you can check for the array key like this:

```php
@foreach($menu as $name => $setting)
  @if($name == 'wallet')
    <!-- do something different for wallet -->
  @else
    <!-- do the regular thing here -->
  @endif
@endforeach
```